# How does Milkor MGL Granade Launcher's trigger and cylinder mechanism work

Tags: firearms

I want to know how does Milkor MGL's trigger and cylinder work. In particular, I am interested in how exactly the trigger action switches the cylinder among the cartridge chambers. As far as i know, the trigger itself works in a basic double action principle, but, I simply, cannot figure by myself how it does manage to rotate the drum forward, it doesn't work like regular pistol revolver but in a rather different manner. The following video demonstrates the basic drum cycle.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMzeIyqHW4Y

I will greatly appreciate if you can give me some sort of diagram or schematic to make things clear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The drum is spring-loaded, so you basically "crank" it by hand after loading rounds;

And then it just rotates by the spring tension after every shot (gas pressure releases the drum lock on top)

Here's a nice explanation: https://youtu.be/BRb2iFkwDC4?t=623

Answer (score 0):

As eyeballpaul said there is a small gas piston in the MGL that releases the drum lock when a round is fired.

Here's a screenshot from World of Guns:

[image]

(World of Guns is a game that allows you to disassemble and view the operation of hundreds of guns.)